# C++ primer 5th edition. Union and members of class type

Tags: c++, unions

I have this text from C++ primer 5th edition. ch 19.6 Union:

> ```
> class Token {
> public:
>     Token(): tok(INT), ival{0} { }
>     Token(const Token &t): tok(t.tok) { copyUnion(t); }
>     Token &operator=(const Token&);
>     ~Token() { if (tok == STR) sval.~string(); }
>     Token &operator=(const std::string&);
>     Token &operator=(char);
>     Token &operator=(int);
>     Token &operator=(double);
> private:
>     enum {INT, CHAR, DBL, STR} tok; // discriminant
>     union {                         // anonymous union
>         char   cval;
>         int    ival;
>         double dval;
>         std::string sval;
>     }; // each Token object has an unnamed member of this unnamed union type
>     // check the discriminant and copy the union member as appropriate
>     void copyUnion(const Token&);
> };
>
> Token &Token::operator=(const std::string &s)
> {
>     if (tok == STR) // if we already hold a string, just do an assignment
>        sval = s;
>     else
>        new(&sval) string(s); // otherwise construct a string
>     tok = STR;                // update the discriminant
>     return *this;
> }
> ```
>
> In this case, if the union already holds a string, we can use the normal string assignment operator to give a new value to that string. Otherwise, there is no existing string object on which to invoke the string assignment operator. Instead, we must construct a string in the memory that holds the union. We do so using placement new (§ 19.1.2, p. 824) to construct a string at the location in which `sval` resides. We initialize that string as a copy of our string parameter. We next update the discriminant and return.

Everything is so straightforward for me but what confuses me is this version of the copy-assignment operator (that takes an `std::string`): and the last paragraph: "if the union already holds a string..." But in case the `union` doesn't hold a `string` then why we bother to use such `placement new`? as long as the assignment operator calls the destructor thus destroys the object then frees memory which is the reverse of the constructor?

I mean why he didn't directly write this?

```
sval = s;
```

I think there's no need to call the dtor explicitly with `sval.~string()` because the assignment operator does that instead. I mean no condition is required.

Comment: Imagine calling the string destructor when the union holds something else, which might be in the bytes pointing to heap-allocated portion of the string's bytes.

Comment: Remember that `sval = s` is the same as `sval.operator=(s)`, and since `sval` hasn't been constructed, this won't work because of the same reasons you can't call any member functions on `sval`.

Comment: @John Kugelman: How can you highlight code inside text quote like you've edited it?

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight code"? Are you asking how I put code inside the blockquote? I did that by putting `>` plus five spaces in front of the code. `"> "` for the blockquote and `"    "` for the code formatting.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: I mean like you did when you edited my code. for example if I want to copy text from a book that contains a code like in my topic.

I start with the line with ">" but cannot show code like yours.

Comment: Check out the [diff](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68877430/revisions) to see exactly what I did. Or look at the [raw Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/d51b01f6-46e6-43d4-8346-50308759af27/view-source).

Comment: @JohnKugelman: Oh great! thanks a lot. I did "> 5 white spaces" and it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot assign something to an object that was never constructed. In C++, any object, any object all, needs to be constructed first, before anything happens to it. This is one of the fundamental rules of C++, without any exceptions or alternatives.

Attempting to use an object in any way, before it is constructed, results in undefined behavior. Assigning to an object counts as using it. Because, after all, if you're assigning something to an object it must exist already.

This is a key, fundamental concept. There is a big difference between constructing an object and assigning something to it. In the first case the object did not exist originally. In the second case it already exists, which  means that at some unspecified prior point in time it must've been constructed.

You are proposing, effectively, to assign something to an object without the benefit of constructing it. This is undefined behavior.

P.S. In modern C++, you can pretty much ignore everything you've read, and simply use `std::variant`, which takes care of all of these details for you. It is true, however, that it is important to understand these kinds of fundamental concepts, and this is a good example that illustrates them. But after you've figured out why things have to be the way they are, here, you can pretty much forget about it, and just use `std::variant`.

> I think there's no need to call the dtor explicitly with
> sval.~string() because the assignment operator does that instead.

No, as a general rule: the assignment operator does not invoke a destructor. The assignment operator, in general, does not destroy an object. If it were, the object would no longer exist, but it does after it's assigned to, of course.

Comment: Thank you first for such useful explanation. Second: If I am not wrong: The problem with the `union` is that it holds allocated uninitialized memory so I need to construct an object there of type `std::string` before trying to assign to it? right? and It was misleading for me because of that fact e.g: `struct Foo{int x_; std::string str_; char c_};` here whenever an object of type `Foo` be constructed, members `x_`, `c_` and a string object (`str_`) is constructed via its def-ctor (std::string()) unlike the `union` where members are not automatically constructed even being of stack memory.

Comment: 1. Right, 2. No, it is logically impossible for all three members of the union to be simultaneously constructed like this. After all, the purpose of the union is that the memory of all of the union's members is common, is shared. And if all three members of a union get constructed, like that, like a `struct`, this results in three different objects existing in the same memory. Accomplishing this feat requires violating several fundamental rules of physics of our shared universe. In this situation, none of the three members are officially constructed.

Comment: I said they (members of the union) are not constructed automatically and of course the compiler doesn't know which is the active member thus to call its constructor that is why they are not initialized in a ctor-init list.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to look at this is to imagine what happens if you do `sval = s` when `sval` does not contain a properly constructed `std::string`.

Assume, for the sake of argument, that `std::string` objects allocate a character array internally to hold the actual data stored in the string (which it pretty much has to do, one way or another).  I'm ignoring short string optimisation here to keep things simple.

Now, when you do `sval = s`, what `sval`'s copy assignment operator is going to do is something like this:

1. Free the existing character array data in `sval`.
2. Allocate space for a new character array and then copy across the character array data from `s`.

If `sval` is not properly initialised then step 1 is going to come unstuck.  The character array data is probably some random pointer value and so, boom!  The same argument applies if you call `sval`'s destructor manually.

Hence the use of placement `new`.  That has no preconditions and constructs a valid, empty `std::string` in `sval` that you can then safely assign to.